# How to retrieve fileID and Guid used in a prefab directly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

is there any method that can return the fileID and corresponding guid of m_Mesh property in a prefab file? The m_Mesh is the mesh that used by the meshfilter component.

How can i get the two values, 4300000 and 8b73e8872ca76104bbca4ee2b704a1b4 via script?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435983/7111561) I think in order to get the according mesh asset you can go through the [`SerializedObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.html) something like e.g.

```
var meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
var so = new SerializedObject(meshFilter);
so.Update();
var meshProperty = so.FindProperty("m_Mesh");
var obj = meshProperty.objectReferenceValue;
```

Now from here you can forward this into the given

> ```
> if (AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier(obj, out var guid, out long file))
> {
>     Debug.Log(
>         $"Asset: {obj.name}\r\n" +
>         $"Instance ID: {obj.GetInstanceID()}\r\n" +
>         $"GUID: {guid}\r\n" +
>         $"File ID: {file}"
>     );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info using the AssetDatabase (editor only).

[AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier.html)

```
if (AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier(obj, out var guid, out long file))
{
    Debug.Log(
        $"Asset: {obj.name}\r\n" +
        $"Instance ID: {obj.GetInstanceID()}\r\n" +
        $"GUID: {guid}\r\n" +
        $"File ID: {file}"
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi，thank you for your reply. After trying , I found this method return the value I want only if the input obj is the mesh that has been used by prefab.How can I get these value from prefab itself but not mesh?

Comment: Are you looking for the guid and file id of the prefab?  You should be able to pass the root of the prefab to the above function and get back the values.  Or are you saying you want to use the prefab object but get the info for the mesh?